# How do I add a delay to the hover?

Tags: hover, delay

I'm trying to add a delay here so that when the user hovers over the menu blocks it doesn't execute right away and waits say .3 seconds before launching the menu. Should I do this via css or jQuery?

```
_mouseOverHandler = function (event) { 
    clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);
    $(event.target) 
        .addClass(this.settings.hoverClass);
    _togglePanel.call(this, event);  
    if ($(event.target).is(':tabbable')) {
        $('html').on('keydown.accessible-megamenu', $.proxy(_keyDownHandler, event.target));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do it by using setTimeout JS function

```
setTimeout(function(){
 // in here you should add what you need to do.
},300);
```

In case you wish to do this by using css you could do it by using transitions

```
.button{
    transition: 0s background-color;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color:blue;    
    transition-delay:.3s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo but it did not work here is the full jquery code that I'm trying to modify: http://adobe-accessibility.github.io/Accessible-Mega-Menu/js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js

Answer (score 0):

The code of Accessible-Mega-Menu doesn't use the `.hover()` function, but it does have both a `_mouseOverHandler` and `_mouseOutHandler`. The following is untested, but I'll try to include the theory and explanation.

Add a new variable to hold a timer, I'll use `navTimer`, into scope. Place this such that both `_mouseOverHandler` and `_mouseOutHandler` can see it.

In `_mouseOverHandler` wrap the operative parts in `window.setTimeout`:

```
navTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(event.target) 
        .addClass(this.settings.hoverClass);
    _togglePanel.call(this, event);  
    if ($(event.target).is(':tabbable')) {
        $('html').on('keydown.accessible-megamenu', $.proxy(_keyDownHandler, event.target));
    }
}, 300);
```

We don't modify the call to `clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);` because we want that to trigger on the mouse activity as it is a separate timer.

Then in `_mouseOutHandler` add the line `window.clearTimeout(navTimer);`

This has the effect that when you mouse in it starts a countdown of 300 milliseconds. If you mouse out it clears this timer. If you stay in the mouse in area for the full time then the events will trigger.

**Step by Step**

1. open your copy of `jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js`
2. at line 151 insert `this.navTimer = null;`
3. after line 650 `clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);` insert `this.navTimer = setTimeout(function(){`
4. before line 658 `});` insert `}, 300);`
5. after line 669 add `clearTimeout(this.navTimer);`

These steps are a little more closely tied to the syntax and style that the file was using than the instructions above, but it is still untested.

**Modified function**

This was the intended edit:

```
_mouseOverHandler = function (event) {
    clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID);
    this.navTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(event.target).addClass(this.settings.hoverClass);
        _togglePanel.call(this, event);
        if ($(event.target).is(':tabbable')) {
            $('html').on('keydown.accessible-megamenu', $.proxy(_keyDownHandler, event.target));
        }
    }, 300);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm not a Jquery expert. Do you know how I can apply your instructions to the code. The Test page is here: http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/test.html 

and the Jquery here: http://terrillthompson.com/tests/menus/accessible-mega-menu/js/jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js

Comment: This is more on the JavaScript side of things than the jQuery side as jQuery is a library of tools for making JavaScript easier to use in the browser and the lines being changed are pure JavaScript. I can modify the answer so that the three changes I suggest include the line numbers within the `jquery-accessibleMegaMenu.js` file, would that be useful?

Comment: Yes sir go ahead and modify.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks again for your time Jason. Will give it a shot now. Have a wonderful afternoon!

Comment: Hey Jason, for step 3 there is no clearTimeout(this.mouseTimeoutID); at line 650 as you mentioned?

Comment: Search for `_mouseOverHandler = function (event) { ` and insert it after the second line in that function.

Comment: When you ask a series of questions all tied to the same larger issue it is helpful to provide links between them.